# Combining string and []byte for payload

Tags: http, go, byte

I'm trying to send an http request with a payload that contains 2 strings and a []byte. Any good ways of going about this? I've tried encryption/decryption (didn't work), converting the []byte to string (since the []byte is an image, it didn't work).

Visual representation:

string1
[]byte
string2

Comment: Use a multipart message. https://golang.org/pkg/mime/multipart/

Comment: @bserdar could you provide an example for use with http.newrequest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example using multipart request. I modified this from a piece of code I have that deals with JSON docs, so there may be some mistakes in it, but it should give you the idea:

```
        body := bytes.Buffer{}
        writer := multipart.NewWriter(&body)
        hdr := textproto.MIMEHeader{}
        hdr.Set("Content-Type", "text/plain")
        part, _ := writer.CreatePart(hdr)
        part.Write(data1)

        hdr = textproto.MIMEHeader{}
        hdr.Set("Content-Type", <image type>)
        part, _ = writer.CreatePart(hdr)
        part.Write(imageData)

        ... // Add more parts if you need to
        writer.Close()

        request, _ := http.NewRequest(http.MethodPost, url, &body)
        request.Header.Set("Content-Type", fmt.Sprintf("multipart/mixed;boundary=%s", writer.Boundary()))

        hcli := http.Client{}
        rsp, err := hcli.Do(request)
```

Comment: could you write something quick that uses http.NewRequest with a body that is formatted like:``` string
[]byte
string```

Comment: The example I have has two parts, a text part and an image part. Just add another text part. You realize, the other end of this, the receiver, has to read this as multipart as well.